# Remove empty elements in 2 different arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, one of which is filled with elements and the other has empty elements, eg:

```
let arr1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'strawberries', 'blueberries', 'pineapple']
let arr2 = [1,,3,,,4]
```

How do I remove both bananas, strawberries and blueberries and the empty element in `arr2`, should look something like this:

```
let arr1 = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pineapple']
let arr2 = [1,3,4]
```

edit: added more elements to the array for scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate and return only the expected value something like the below snippet

After edit please follow the below snippet

```js
let arr1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges']
let arr2 = [1, , 3]
var filtered = arr2.filter((item, index) => {
  if (arr2[index] != null) {
    arr1.splice(index, index);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false
  }
});

console.log(filtered);
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: how do I scale this for more elements in arr1? I don't wanna hardcode the word 'bananas'

Comment: if you dont want to give bananas, What is the strategy how would you like to remove the elements ? I mean on what basis. Please let me know I am not able to understand that part

Comment: edited the question for a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let arr1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'strawberries', 'blueberries', 'pineapple'];
let arr2 = [1,,3,,,4];
arr1 = arr1.filter((x, i) => arr2[i] !== undefined);
arr2 = arr2.filter(x => x !== undefined);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: how do i make it so it doesn't filter out 0

Comment: @LittleBall Updated to deal with 0s, your example didn't start from 0, I thought if you had more items they would be larger numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could map and filter with `true` because filter omits sparse items.

```js
let array1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'],
    array2 = [1, , 3],
    result1 = array2.map((_, i) => array1[i]).filter(_ => true),
    result2 = array2.filter(_ => true);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
let arr1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'strawberries', 'blueberries', 'pineapple']
let arr2 = [1,,3,,,4]

let result = arr1.filter((item, index) => {
    return arr2[index] !== undefined;
});

console.log(result); // Outputs: ["apples", "oranges", "pineapple"]
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/fkvxrn9h/7/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterOutItems = (array, itemValue = undefined) {
  if (typeof itemValue == undefined) {
    return array.filter((el) => !!el);
  } else {
    return array.filter((el) => el != itemValue);
  }
}
```

The filter method will return only the items that satisfy the predicate.